# Adding dynamic fields on pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I want to develop a form which has rows of multiple input fields. I am using jQuery to achieve this. The problem is that when I am clicking on the add row button, the new row is disappearing very quickly from the page. The rows are not permanent on page. What can I do to make them stay on the page?

```js
$("#addrows").click(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td></td>';
  html += '<td></td>';
  html += '<td> <input type="text" name="task[]" id="task" placeholder="Task" /></td>';
  html += '<td> <input type="number" name="time[]" id="time" value="0" style="width:40px;" /></td>';
  html += '<td> <button class="remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';

  $("#table-items").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="table-responsive" id="div1">
    <table id="table-items" class="table bordered-table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Select Project</td>
        <td>Select Activity</td>
        <td>Task description</td>
        <td>Time (hrs)</td>
        <td><button id="addrows">Add Rows</button> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because by default `button` elements are `type="submit"`, which means your `form` element is refreshing the page. The same is happening on your `remove` button.

To fix this, add a `type="button"` attribute to the buttons:

```js
$("#addrows").click(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td></td>';
  html += '<td></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="task[]" id="task" placeholder="Task" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" name="time[]" id="time" value="0" style="width:40px;" /></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';

  $("#table-items").append(html);
});

$('#div1').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="table-responsive" id="div1">
    <table id="table-items" class="table bordered-table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Select Project</td>
        <td>Select Activity</td>
        <td>Task description</td>
        <td>Time (hrs)</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="addrows">Add Rows</button> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also note that I added the missing `</div>` tag in to your HTML, and the logic for removing the each appended `tr`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: I had another question that i wanted to ask for the same context, In above script tag two tables columns are empty, html += '<td></td>';
  html += '<td></td>'; , actually i want select box there, but i want to retrieve options from database using php , how can i do that.

Comment: That's an entirely separate issue which you should start a new question for.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It helped me a lot @Rory McCrosan